# The tags long-short-term-memory and lstm should be synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are the tags [lstm](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lstm) and [long-short-term-memory](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/long-short-term-memory), but they are not marked as synonyms. Of course, the questions associated with one tag should be merged with the questions associated with the other tag.

Comment: This has already been solved, for those of you reading this.